# elisp: syntax error on do clause

Tags: loops, syntax-error, lisp, elisp

I am writing a Greatest Common Factor function.

I kept getting errors saying

> "(if t (set q).....)" is not valid syntax

and so I commented it out. But then I was told that my do syntax is invalid.

> syntax error on the 'do' clause

But I'm looking at it and seeing no errors. Why will my code not work?

```
(defun myGCD (a b)
"My function, which returns the Greatest Common Factor"
(let ((x a) (y b) (z 0)) 
  (loop until (or (zerop x) (zerop y))
    do ( ;(progn
      ;(if t ;(< a b)
        ; If case
        ;((setq b (- b a)) (setq c a))
        ; Else case
        ;((setq a (- a b)) (setq c b))
      ;)
      ;(return c)
    );)
  )
)
)

(myGCD 10 20)
```

Comment: The if- and else-clauses can't have those extra parentheses around them. `setq` can set multiple variables at once, so you can just do `(setq b (- b a) c a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have basic syntax errors in your code.**

In a LOOP form you need to have one or more compound forms after a DO.

```
(loop ... do () )
```

is not allowed, because `()` is not a compound form.

Also note that parentheses are not grouping expressions in a sequence.

```
((foo 1) (bar 2))
```

above is not valid Lisp. In Scheme it might be correct, but there the first form then needs to return a function.

To group expressions you would need something like `progn`, which allows embedded forms and returns the values of the last one:

```
(progn
  (foo 4)
  (bar 2))
```

Above is valid.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, you can't have an empty 'do' command. This doesn't explain why the other logic was failing, but I will look at that some more.